# Setting label text in a UICollectionViewCell not working when string is passed to custom class

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewdelegate

I am setting up a UICollectionView with a custom UICollectionViewCell Class.

Using the functions specified in the UICollectionViewDelegate I have been able to get a label populated with text in each cell.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "keypadButton", for: indexPath) as! KeypadButtonCollectionViewCell
    cell.awakeFromNib()
    return cell
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let button = cell as! KeypadButtonCollectionViewCell

    //Assigning like this works
    button.buttonLabel.text = tempScale[indexPath.row] 
}
```

However;

I initially had it set up differently with a `buttonText` class variable in the `KeypadButtonCollectionViewCell` Class (as below) and setting that variable in the `willDisplay` function (also below)

```
class KeypadButtonCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {


    var buttonLabel: UILabel!
    var buttonText: String!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        buttonLabel = UILabel.init(frame: contentView.frame)
        buttonLabel.font = UIFont.init(name: "HelveticaNeue-Ultralight", size: 20)
        buttonLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
        buttonLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center

        buttonLabel.text = buttonText //Assigning here didn't work

        contentView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.init(red: 37/255, green: 37/255, blue: 37/255, alpha: 1).cgColor
        contentView.layer.borderWidth = 4
        contentView.addSubview(buttonLabel)

    }

}


//---------In the view controller--------

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let button = cell as! KeypadButtonCollectionViewCell

    //Setting class var string here to be set as label.text not working
    button.labelText = tempScale[indexPath.row] 
}
```

What is it I am misunderstanding here? Why did it not like setting the using the assigned class variable to set the label text in the wakeFromNib() method but worked when I set the label text directly?

As mentioned at the beginning, I have a working way of doing this, I am interested in this for academia and to better understand OOP programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awakeFromNib` gets called automatically after the `view` and its `subviews` were allocated and initialized, so don't called it explicitly. So remove the line  `cell.awakeFromNib()`.

In your case when `awakeFromNib` is called your `buttonText` String is `nil` and  when `willDisplay cell` method call where you are setting String value `buttonText` but `awakeFromNib` is already called before that so setting `buttonText` there will not update the value of your `label`.

From the documentation on [`awakeFromNib`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/objectivec/nsobject/1402907-awakefromnib):

> The nib-loading infrastructure sends an awakeFromNib message to each object recreated from a nib archive, but only after all the objects in the archive have been loaded and initialized. **When an object receives an awakeFromNib message, it is guaranteed to have all its outlet and action connections already established.**

The way you are doing with your first approach is perfect by setting array element directly to the label's text but if you want to set the String value `buttonText` then you can go for the observing property `didSet` of your `buttonText` like this way.

```
var buttonText: String = "" {
    didSet {
        buttonLabel.text = buttonText
    }
}
```

Now when you set `buttonText` value in `willDisplay cell` it will update the value of cell's label because of `didSet` of your `buttonText`.